# R Shiny - Understanding the difference between observe and observeEvent when updating mutually dependent inputs

Tags: r, shiny

The app below has two mutually dependent numericInputs, `a` and `b`. The value of `input$a` is `1-input$b` and the value of `input$b` is `1-input$a`. Whenever the user changes an input's value, I would like to update the value of the other accordingly. The code below contains two approaches:

1. A single observer
2. Two separate observers - one that listens for changes to a and updates b and another that listens to `b` and updates `a`.

When I try 1), the inputs get stuck in an infinite loop but I'm not sure I understand why. If the user changes `b`, then the observer is triggered and the value of `a` gets updated to be `1-b`. Since the values of both inputs are now up-to-date, there are no further changes to `input$a` or `input$b` and the observer shouldn't be triggered again until the user makes another change. But this isn't the case.

How exactly does approach 1) differ from approach 2)? Why does 1) get stuck in a loop whereas 2) doesn't?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    numericInput('a','a', value = 0.5, max = 1, min = 0),
    numericInput('b','b', value = 0.5, max = 1, min = 0)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # Using a single observer ----
    observe({

      updateNumericInput(session, 'a', value = 1-req(input$b))

      updateNumericInput(session, 'b', value = 1-req(input$a))

      print(input$a)

    })

    # Using separate observers ----
    # observeEvent(input$b, {
    #   updateNumericInput(session, 'a', value = 1-input$b)
    # })
    # 
    # observeEvent(input$a, {
    #   updateNumericInput(session, 'b', value = 1-input$a)
    # })

  }
)
```

Answer (score 6):

In the documentation of `observe` and `observeEvent`, it is written:

- `observe`

> An observer is like a reactive expression in that it can read reactive values and call reactive expressions, and will automatically re-execute when those dependencies change. [...] [O]bservers use eager evaluation; as soon as their dependencies change, they schedule themselves to re-execute.

In your example, `observe` never stops "observing" and updates the input as soon as the other changes, even if the user doesn't do anything. Therefore, you stay in an infinite loop since each of the two inputs depends on the other.

- `observeEvent`

> [S]ometimes you want to wait for a specific action to be taken from the user, like clicking an actionButton(), before calculating an expression or taking an action. [...] Use observeEvent whenever you want to perform an action in response to an event.

Therefore, `observeEvent` needs the user to make an action to run the function inside. In your example, input "a" will be updated only if the user *manually* changes input "b" and vice-versa. That's why `observeEvent` works in this scenario and `observe` does not.

**Edit:** to have clearer results of the loop created when using `observe`, here's a slightly modified version of the example in the OP:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    numericInput('a','a', value = NULL, max = 1, min = 0),
    numericInput('b','b', value = NULL, max = 1, min = 0)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # Using a single observer ----
    observe({

      updateNumericInput(session, 'a', value = 1-req(input$b))

      updateNumericInput(session, 'b', value = 1-req(input$a))

      print(paste0("a = ", input$a))
      print(paste0("b = ", input$b))

    })


    # Using separate observers ----
    # observeEvent(input$b, {
    #   updateNumericInput(session, 'a', value = 1-input$b)
    # })
    # 
    # observeEvent(input$a, {
    #   updateNumericInput(session, 'b', value = 1-input$a)
    # })

  }
)
```

Careful with the interpretation: the beginning values of `a` and `b` are printed. Then, the new values of `a` and `b` are created but the new value of `b` depends on the first value of `a` (not on the second value of `a`). The third values of `a` and `b` will depend on the second values of `a` and `b`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bretauv. I'm aware that `observe` uses eager evaluation but so does `observeEvent`, right? What I'm confused about is why `observe` is triggered even after its dependencies have finished changing. Say the user changes `b` to 0.54. Then the value of `a` is updated to 0.46. There are no more changes to either input so why is the `observe` running? As the print out in the console shows, the value of `input$a` keeps oscillating between 0.5 and 0.46.

Comment: "eager evaluation" is not mentioned in the documentation of ```observeEvent``` so I suppose it does not use it. As said in my answer, ```observe``` does not care if the modification of the input is manual or is the result of an automatic computation: as long as one of the inputs changes, it will continue to compute. ```observeEvent``` does not: it computes the new value of the input only if the value of the other input is changed manually. Suppose you manually change input ```a```. Then the value of input ```b``` changes since ```observeEvent``` detects a change in ```a``` ... (continued)

Comment: ... However, the modification of ```b``` is automatic, not manual. Therefore, ```observeEvent``` is not triggered by the change in input ```b```, and you don't stay in an infinite loop. Now, why do your values keep oscillating between 0.5 and 0.46 if you change ```b``` to 0.54? First, it is because you forgot to put ```print(input$b)``` below the first ```print``` so only the value of ```a``` is printed. Moreover, ```print(input$a)``` also prints the value at the beginning of the app (0.5). I've edited my post so that the output is clearer.

Comment: It's not true that "`observeEvent` needs the user to make an action to run the function inside". The action can be triggered by any change in a reactive expression, even if it's not caused directly by a user.

Answer (score 3):

In first case the observer looks at all its dependencies, here `input$a` and `input$b`. If anything changes it fires its code. Now, when `a` or `b` changes the observer updates numericInputs. But it notifies the observer that its dependencies changed and it has to run again. That's why you end up with an infinite loop.

When you use `observeEvent`s it's a little bit different. Suppose you set `a = 1`. One of the observers is triggered and it updates `b`, so `b = 0`. Now, the other observer is triggered and it updates `a`, so `a = 1`. But in this case, the new value is exactly the same as the old one, so internal mechanisms of reactivity in shiny stops it from invalidating `a` again since it would be redundant.